# @Transactional isn't working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session, spring-data

I have a class annotated with @Service that is implementing javax.jms.MessageListener, inside the onMessage function i am retrieving an object from a repository, but when i try to preload the lazy loaded properties i get the "could not initialize proxy - no Session" exception.

I prefer not to disable lazy loading as the page entity gets really big with a lot of sub entities and most of the times i don't need these sub entities while working with the page object.

I found and tried a lot of other questions and solutions on google but none of them seem to make a difference for me.

```
@Service
public class PageService implements MessageListener {
    private PageRepository pageRepository;
    public PageService(PageRepository pageRepository){
        this.pageRepository = pageRepository;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        // Message handling etc etc..
        int id = ....
        Page page = pageRepository.findOne(id); // Page is retrieved successfully

        page.InitializeAll(); // <--- Error happens here

        // Build response message.
    }
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Page {
    ....

    @OrderBy("id ASC")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "page", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<Row> rows;

    public void InitializeAll(){
        Hibernate.initialize(this.rows);      // <--- Error
        rows.forEach(r -> r.InitializeAll());
    }
}
```

Page repository is just extending CrudRepository:

```
public interface PageRepository extends CrudRepository<Page, Integer>
```

in another file in the same package(/folder) i have another function annotated with @Transactional with the same function calls inside and here it's all working fine.

```
@MessageMapping("/page/{id}/request")
@SendToUser(value = "/queue/private", broadcast = false)
@Transactional
public initialPageMessage subscribeClient(@DestinationVariable("id") int pageId) {
    initialPageMessage resp = new initialPageMessage();
    resp.page = pageRepository.findOne(pageId);
    resp.page.InitializeAll();
    return resp;
 }
```

TransactionManagerConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TransactionManagerConfiguration {
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    private DataSource datasource;

    public TransactionManagerConfiguration(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory, DataSource datasource){
        this.entityManagerFactory = entityManagerFactory;
        this.datasource = datasource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(){
        JpaTransactionManager tm = new JpaTransactionManager();
        tm.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        tm.setDataSource(datasource);
        return tm;
    }
}
```

Stacktrace

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: models.Page.rows, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:587) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:204) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.forceInitialization(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:739) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.Hibernate.initialize(Hibernate.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at models.Page.InitializeAll(Page.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at controllers.PageService.processMessage(PageService.java:93) ~[classes/:na]
    at controllers.PageService.onMessage(PageService.java:75) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.dispatch(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:1401) ~[activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.dispatch(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:131) [activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.iterate(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:202) [activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:133) [activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:48) [activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_40]
```

Comment: Can you add the code or configuration where you enable transactions?

Comment: @manish added my configuration, the connection configuration is done using spring.datasource.* in application.properties

Comment: Can you try `@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)`? The default value of `proxyTargetClass` is `false`, which means that Spring will generate a proxy object for the interface (which in your case is `MessageListener`). Changing the value to `true` will force the proxy object to be generated for the class instead and since class methods are correctly annotated with `@Transactional`, the transactions should work as expected.

Comment: It gave me the same exception, I've added a trace as well, i don't know if it should but the trace shows nothing that looks like a proxy class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sometime i found the issue, the problem was that the 'onMessage' method was called from inside the same class. This prevented the @Transactional proxy (wrapping the class) from being called. When i moved the @Transactional to another class and called the function from outside that class it started to work.